# scroll to top .offset() using percentage %

Tags: jquery, scroll, offset

I just wrote this for scrolling pages which is working fine and does what it should..

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){

var sid = $(this).attr('id');

$('html,body').animate({
 scrollTop: $('#'+ sid +'-content').offset().top - 200}, 1000);
  return false;
});
```

..but I want the offset to be calculated by % rather then px

ie rather then

```
top - 200
```

it could be

```
top - 30%
```

any ideas how to accomplish this?

As always any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

***Quick Edit:***

The current 3 answers (thank you) seem to multiply each time  which is not what I want, I wish to have a constant gap of 30% window height each time so each time the #id-content is scrolled to the top lines up with a fixed positioned sidebar I have.

My current code leaves a 200px gap but that causes an issue with different monitor/browser sizes where as a % would sort it out.

Answer (score 6):

The following will position the box always 60% from the top:

```
var offset = parseInt($('#example').offset().top);
var bheight = $(window).height();
var percent = 0.6;
var hpercent = bheight * percent;
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: offset - hpercent}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate 30% of the offset and use that:

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){

    var sid = $(this).attr('id');
    var offset = $('#'+ sid +'-content').offset().top;

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: offset - (offset * 0.3)}, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/rkWDR/5/) showing this in action.

Comment: It didn't work because I had an extra closing `});` for some reason! I've fixed it now.

Comment: That fixed it but again all three answers seem to multiply each time, I just want a constant 30% gap from top css equivilent: position:absolute;top:30%;

Answer (score 1):

I know this is years old and the OP has most likely found a solution by now, but here's my simple solution for anyone who comes across this anyway..

```
  var navBarHeight = $('#navBar').height();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#scrollDestination").offset().top-navbarheight
            }, 1000);
```

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for contributing. This is good solution, but it is practically identical to at least one other answer (and similar to several of the others). When you have a little more reputation, you can comment and suggest edits to other posts.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want 30% of, but what you can do is just multiply what you want a percentage of by 0.3, and then subtract that from top.

If it's the top offset itself you want 30% of:

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#'+ sid +'-content').offset().top - $('#'+ sid +'-content').offset().top * 0.3 }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Of course that seems a bit silly, since it's just equivalent to `$('#'+ sid +'-content').offset().top * 0.7`, but you can replace it with whatever you want.

Comment: Yes its the top offset I want, as my coding stands its scrolls leaving 200px gap from top to id. I just tested your code and it kind of does what I want but it multiplys each time ie link 1 = 30%, link 2 = 60%, link 3 = 90% and so on, I want it so the gap from top to id is always 30%

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){

var sid = $(this).attr('id');
var contentTop = $('#'+ sid +'-content').offset().top;
contentTop = parseInt(contentTop - (contentTop *0.3)); 
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: contentTop }, 1000);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This basicly does the same as nomulous code it multiplys each time (see comment above)

Comment: May be we both posted the answer almost at the same time.

Comment: Yeah not saying you rewrote his code just that it does the same thing which I dont want it multiplys each time :)