# Scroll to top/bottom using percentage in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I've made a page navigation with a scroll to top and to bottom button. The problem is: using simple values except of percentages one of my buttons won't appear because of less content.

So my question is how to change the code so that the button will change if you reach e.g. 60% or less than 60% of the page?

I've read different posts for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736582/scroll-to-top-offset-using-percentage) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512871/scroll-to-top-and-scroll-to-bottom-in-jquery) but the code doesn't fit my needs or I don't know how to use them for my custom code.

```js
jQuery(function($){

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (y > 1500) {
      $(this).find('.icon-arrow-m').removeClass('icon-arrow-m');
      $('a.scroll:nth-child(1) > i:nth-child(1)').addClass("icon-arrow-up");
  } else if (y <= 1500){
      $(this).find('.icon-arrow-up').removeClass('icon-arrow-up');
      $('a.scroll:nth-child(1) > i:nth-child(1)').addClass('icon-arrow-m');
  }
});

 $(".scroll").click(function(event){
    var y = $(document).scrollTop();
    var down = y+4800;
   if($(this).find('.icon-arrow-up').hasClass('icon-arrow-up')) {
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0'}, 800);
    } else {
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: down}, 800);
    }
   
   
 });
});
```

To test the code, you can go my [main page](http://web1139.server.inventmedia.de/Biogas_Brazil/) where I'm using this script.

**Updated code - fixed scroll to bottom**

```js
 jQuery(function($){

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (y > 1500) {
      $(this).find('.icon-arrow-m').removeClass('icon-arrow-m');
      $('a.scroll:nth-child(1) > i:nth-child(1)').addClass("icon-arrow-up");
  } else if (y <= 1500){
      $(this).find('.icon-arrow-up').removeClass('icon-arrow-up');
      $('a.scroll:nth-child(1) > i:nth-child(1)').addClass('icon-arrow-m');
  }
});

 $(".scroll").click(function(event){
    var y = $(document).scrollTop();
    var down = y+4800;
   if($(this).find('.icon-arrow-up').hasClass('icon-arrow-up')) {
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0'}, 800);
    } else {
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:  $(document).height()}, 800);
    }
   
   
 });
});
```

Comment: I've been looking at your live site, can you confirm the problem is relative to the scroll bottom function not reaching the actual bottom of the page?

Comment: Yes, the button doesn't scroll completely.

Comment: can you try this? `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 800);`

Comment: Ok, scrolling to bottom should work correct now. Could it be the issue for the scrolling problem? I can't find any problems on the other pages. EDIT: On  [this page](http://web1139.server.inventmedia.de/Biogas_Brazil/aus-und-weiterbildung/) there's still a problem.

Comment: I think that happens because the page is shorter than 1500px. You should consider a different approach esablishing if the page was scrolled more or less than 50%.

Comment: That's why I need some help with the code. I've found different codes for percent values, but I'm not firm using jquery to put it correctly inside my script.

Comment: I'm going to try and articulate an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate 50% dividing by 2 the height of the page (see `var x` in code snippet):

```js
 jQuery(function($){

$(document).scroll(function() {

  var y = $(document).scrollTop(); // AMOUNT OF SCROLL FROM TOP
  var x = $(document).height() / 2; // HALF OF PAGE HEIGHT

  if (y > x) { // SCROLL IS OVER 50% OF PAGE HEIGHT
      $(this).find('.icon-arrow-m').removeClass('icon-arrow-m');
      $('a.scroll:nth-child(1) > i:nth-child(1)').addClass("icon-arrow-up");
  } else { // SCROLL IS LESS THAN 50% OF PAGE HEIGHT
      $(this).find('.icon-arrow-up').removeClass('icon-arrow-up');
      $('a.scroll:nth-child(1) > i:nth-child(1)').addClass('icon-arrow-m');
  }
});

 $(".scroll").click(function(event){
   if($(this).find('.icon-arrow-up').hasClass('icon-arrow-up')) {
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0'}, 800);
    } else {
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:  $(document).height()}, 800);
    }
   
   
 });
});
```

Comment: I guess this is exactly what I'm looking for. Can't find any issues and this works also on pages with the shortest content height.

Comment: glad to hear that